# Vega lite Top 10 order host descending based on the sum of field score

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have this example data

```
"values": [
  {"host": "host-one", "score": 70, date: 1593674604},
  {"host": "host-two", "score": 30, date: 1593674608},
  {"host": "host-three", "score": 12, date: 1593674615},
  {"host": "host-two", "score": 95, date: 1593674624},
  {"host": "host-three", "score": 1, date: 1593674633}    
]
```

In a heatmap I have to show top 10 host, based on the sum of the score per host, in the y axis, I have tried in many ways without success, this is what I have tried the last time:

```
 }
  transform: [
    {calculate: "datum.key.date", as: "date"}
    {calculate: "datum.key.host", as: "host"}
    {calculate: "datum.key.score", as: "score"}
    {
      window: [
        {op: "sum", field: "score", as: "score_order"}
      ]
    }
    groupby: ["host"]
  ]
  mark: {type: "rect", cornerRadius: 3}
  encoding: {
    x: {
      bin: {maxbins: 80}
      field: date
      type: temporal
    }
    y: {
      field: host
      type: ordinal
      sort: {field: "score_order", order: "descending"}
    }
```

Any clues on what Im doing wrong?